# Filter for rows with column condition on an array

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-sql

I have a table `my_table`:

```
id  x_id type
--- ---- ----
1    31   a
2    14   b
3    31   c
4    12   c
5    31   b
6    12   c
7    14   a
```

I want to return all rows where `x_id` has a `type` meeting all elements in the array `arr`.

**Edit: However, the actual values in that array and their number are unknown but would be possible values of the column `type`. There is always at least one value in `arr`.**

So for `arr = [b, c]`, I should get the following result:

```
id  x_id type
--- ---- ----
3    31   c
5    31   b
```

How would I write a query to get such a result?

Note: I'm not really familiar with `sql` commands so please help me edit my question if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: can you explain me your criteria for getting 31 as the X_id in the result set?

Comment: @developer 31 because there are at least two rows where `x_id=31` for `type=b` and `type=c`

Comment: @Julio are you saying that the number of items in the array (currently 2) might sometimes be 3, other times 4, etc.? If so how are you determining what items within the array are of interest? In other words, what makes b and c part of the array of interest? If there is no consistent logic to determining that, then I believe what you are describing requires dynamic sql (not just plain standard sql).

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Yes, the number of values in the array can be anything, or at the very least there would be one value (I should mention that). I'll add the dynamic sql tag.

In the example above I used b and c to illustrate my example, it could have been `[a]`, `[a,b,c]`, or even `[d,e,f,g]`. But when I have `[a,b]` for my example I expect `x_id=31`.

Comment: @Julio for what reason (business logic speaking) would it be [a,b,c] vs. [d,e,f,g] ? What determines what items are in the array?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia ok, let's say `type` in the table can be any of a,b,c,d,e,f,g. A user is given an interface where they can choose one or more from a,b,c,d. The system should return x_id with a type that match all the elements the user selected. In my example the user happens to have selected b and c from the pool a,b,c,d.

Comment: @Julio what language are you using, PHP? Can you get what the user selects into a variable which stores of a value of 'a','b','c' and then use that variable in the query? If in one way or another you can have a variable that shows the list in that form, I think you could do it in plain sql.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I'm using ruby on rails. I realize that it's easier to compose the query when each element is individually selected but I don't think it would be possible to use anything other than the array to query.

Comment: @Julio see my edit, depends on whether you're able to get a variable to hold the necessary values I think, I don't know any ruby so can't help you there. The query below would conform better to variables in general though as the structure of the query doesn't need to change, just the particular spots where you could use the variable, assuming you're able to make a var store the necessary things in the necessary format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
  from my_table
 where x_id in (select x.x_id
                  from (select x_id from my_table where type = 'b') x
                  join (select x_id from my_table where type = 'c') y
                    on x.x_id = y.x_id)
   and type in ('b', 'c')
```

**Fiddle test:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8601/2/0

This might conform better to variables (having one variable to hold the list of types in 'b','c' format and another variable to hold the count of the types. Is there any way you can get a variable to hold what's in the array as that value: `'b','c'` ?

```
select *
  from my_table
 where x_id in (select x_id
                  from my_table
                 where type in ('b', 'c')
                 group by x_id
                having count(distinct type) = 2)
   and type in ('b', 'c')
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8601/12/0

So you would use the variable in the 2 `type in ()` spots (variable inside the `()`) and the variable holding the count in place of the 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat ugly way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE x_id IN
(
    SELECT x_id FROM
    (
        SELECT x_id, type
        FROM my_table x
        WHERE type IN ('b', 'c')
        GROUP BY x_id, type
    ) y
    GROUP BY x_id
    HAVING COUNT(x_id) = 2
) AND type IN ('b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `my_table` 
WHERE 
  `type` IN ("b","c")
```

Comment: this will give all the types of b and c, he wants the top of each type